# Precision issue bouding sphere

Tags: c++, directx11, precision

I tried to make two spheres with bounding sphere to detect collision so they stop when they collide. But it seems that im having a precision issue. They stey stuck together because of small decimal keeping it stuck. Is there a way around this? Since they are in a 3d space, adding or subtracting a little off seems impossible and expensive. How can I solve these precision issues?

```
 oldleftright = leftright, oldupdown = updown;

if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT))
    leftright += 0.0001;
if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT))
    leftright -= 0.0001;
if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN))
    updown -= 0.0001;
if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP))
    updown += 0.0001;

collide = test.Intersect(test2);
if (collide)
{
    leftright = oldleftright;
    updown = oldupdown;
}
collide = false;
```

Comment: Without knowing what test.Intersect looks like, it's really difficult to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly here is how I usually solve it: check if the two sphere are approaching themselves or not.

If yes then they are actually colliding and the result of delta_Speed dot delta_Position will be > 0 (the angle between the two vector wil be < 90°)

[image]

In code you will have:

```
vector3 deltaPos = pos1 - pos2;
vector3 deltaSpeed = speed1 - speed2;
bool collide = deltaPos * deltaSpeed > 0.0f; //deltaPos.x*deltaSpeed.x + deltaPos.y*deltaSpeed.y + deltaPos.z*deltaSpeed.z > 0.0f
```